# XRANDR: HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

Tags: xrandr

I can't get the HDMI to work with a 
 - MSI laptop
 - NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX1060
 - UBUNTU 18.04

I have run:
- sudo apt install nvidia-driver-version-number

But hasn't work

Comment: Which driver version number did you select? Eg 390 or 396 or 418,  etc.

Comment: driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended